# Null as parameter default value in scala produces type mismatch error

Tags: scala, types, null

In order to make overloaded calls like

```
val myPage: DocumentType;
func()
func(myPage)
```

I wrote a function:

```
def func(page: DocumentType = null): Unit = {...}
```

but receive the following error:

```
type mismatch; found : Null(null) required: DocumentType
```

When I change DocumentType to String, the error disappears. First question: why?
DocumentType is a type from the library which I cannot change, with the following definition:

```
type DocumentType <: Document
trait Document
```

I do not want on each client call to wrap actual parameter to Option (like `Option(myPage)`) but are there any other options to obtain the similar?

Comment: Can you share or point to the definition of `DocumentType`?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez 1) type DocumentType <: Document
2) trait Document

Answer (score 2):

You can just overload functions like

```
def func(): Unit = { }  // do what you would do with null
def func(page: DocumentType): Unit = { }  // do what you would do with a DocumentType
```

You can abstract the implementation by getting both to call some other private function to keep it DRY. You can then call `func()` or `func(new DocumentType())`

**ORIGINAL ANSWER** (not so good)

```
def func(page: DocumentType): Unit = func(Some(page))
def func(page: Option[DocumentType] = None): Unit = ???
```

means you don't need to resort to `null`. You lose the clean API, as you can call

```
val d = new DocumentType()
func()
func(d)
func(Some(d))
func(None)
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Just for education purposes, is there any possibility to to keep null?

Comment: @AlexStamper it's generally recommended to avoid null if at all possible

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
trait Document

trait DocumentFunc {
  // The trick is to tell the compiler that your type can be nullable.
  type DocumentType >: Null <: Document

  def fun(page: DocumentType = None.orNull): Unit = {
    println(page)
  }
}
```

Apparently, the problem is that since you only set the upper bound to `Document`, the compiler will reject `null`, because `DocumentType` could be overridden to be `Nothing`.
And *"obviously"*, `null` could not be used in a place where a `Nothing` is expected.

**First disclaimer:** I agree with Joel Berkeley, that you should avoid `null` and I would prefer his solution.
I just wanted to answer the real question: *"Why it does not work"*.

**Second disclaimer:** I used `None.orNull` just to not have an explicit `null` - that is just because the linters I use disallow the use of `null`.
You may change it if you want.

**Third disclaimer:** `Type Members` can almost always be changed by `Type Parameters`, which are *(usually)* more easier to use, and more *"typesafe"*.
`Type Members`, *IMHO*, should only be used when you really need them, like `path dependent types` - More info can be found [here](https://typelevel.org/blog/2015/07/13/type-members-parameters.html).

**Fourth disclaimer:** The use of `null` and `Unit` *(together with `vars` if you had)*, is a symptom of using **Scala** as **Java**, which is *(usually)* a bad use of the language. However, that is just my opinion.